# Update Columns of one table based on another table

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, data-manipulation

So, I have been trying to update table columns with other table columns.
Eg: SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM T1

[image]

SELECT COL11, COL21 FROM T2.

[image]

When the values are updated in T2, I want to update them in T1 also.
For eg: If after manipulating values in T2, the resultset of "SELECT COL11, COL21 FROM T2;" is:

[image]

then, the resultset of SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM T1 should be:

[image]

I have tried several queries, but it is easier to update if there weren't multiple values in COL2 of T1, need a bit of help here!

Comment: I don't understand how these two tables are related to eachother. Like... Why would the second row in T1 get updated? There is no relationship between either `1000041` or `00062` in `T2`. Like, those values don't even exist in `T2` so how would you know to update `T1.Col1` when `T2` changes?

Comment: Why is your title in all-caps?

Comment: Do you really name your attributes COL1, COL2, ....? A database is NOT a spreadsheet?